# Remote Interpreter Reinitialized

Tags: warnings

Every time i run a Python program in PyScripter I get this message - "**Remote Interpreter Reinitialized**". Though the program runs fine but I don't understand the meaning of this message.

What does it mean? and why is this message thrown every time?

I was just running Python programs.